# setOnCompletionListener is detecting the completion only for first time

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, playlist

`setOnCompletionListener` is detecting the completion of a song the first time only. In the code below `song1` and `song2` are played one after the other but the remaining songs are not being played.

I want to play the songs one by one and add some silence between songs.

```
MediaPlayer song0=new MediaPlayer();
     int track = 0;
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  song0=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.song1);
 play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               function();
             }
        });

        song0.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer song0) {
                track++;
                loadsong();

                function();
            }

        });
    }
    void loadsong()
    {

        if(track==1)        song0=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.song2);
        if(track==2)        song0=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.song3);
        if(track==3)        song0=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.song4);
    }**strong text**


    void function(){
        if(track<4) song0.start();
        else
            song0.stop();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `onclickListener` event only starting for once. If you want to play song one by one you have to create a loop or have to do it recursively. Here's a snippet where I used  `song0.setOnCompletionListener` inside `loadsong()` and in the event recursively called `loadsong()` every time. Changed your `loadsong()` method a little bit. Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button play;
MediaPlayer song0 = new MediaPlayer();
int track = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    play = findViewById(R.id.play);

    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            loadsong();
        }
    });


}


void loadsong() {
    track++;
    if (track == 1) {
        song0 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track1);
        song0.start();
    }else if (track == 2) {
        song0 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track2);
        song0.start();
    }else if (track == 3) {
        song0 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track3);
        song0.start();
    }else if (track > 3) {
        song0.stop();
    }

    song0.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer song) {
            song.stop();
            loadsong();
        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you create MediaPlayer object every time you need to play songs. So you need to set OnCompletionListener every time after creating MediaPlayer object for another song.

So you can change a few lines in your code to fix the issue.

```
MediaPlayer song0=new MediaPlayer();
int track = 0;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    song0=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.song1);
    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               function();
             }
        });

        song0.setOnCompletionListener(m_CompletionListener);
    }
    void loadsong()
    {

        if(track==1) {
        song0=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.song2); 
        song0.setOnCompletionListener(m_CompletionListener); 
    }
        if(track==2) {
        song0=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.song3); 
        song0.setOnCompletionListener(m_CompletionListener); 
    }

        if(track==3) {
        song0=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.song4); 
        song0.setOnCompletionListener(m_CompletionListener); 
    }

    }**strong text**


    void function(){
        if(track<4) song0.start();
        else
            song0.stop();

    }
    MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener m_CompletionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer song0) {
                track++;
                loadsong();
                function();
            }

        };
```

Another way to implement is to create only one MediaPlayer object and instead of creating MediaPlayer object everytime, call setDataSource function for playing other songs.
If you need this way more detail, i can make sample code also.

I hope it will help you!